# Launching app on simulator crashes Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, ios-simulator, osx-mavericks

I have created an empty iOS project in `Xcode 5.0.2` on OSx `Mavericks`. When I click `Play button` to launch the app on the iPhone simulator, the Xcode **crashes**. I have disabled the source control feature of Xcode also but still it crashes when I click the play button. Here is the crash log.

```
Process:         Xcode [1484]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0.2 (3335.32)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335032000000000~4
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [138]
Responsible:     Xcode [1484]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-04-13 09:13:37.899 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A476u)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  7C2BACB3-50DC-AAE3-93F3-1C62CA3A1868


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Sending performRunAction: to <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7fe12d932b50> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7fe12d932b50>
ProductBuildVersion: 5A3005
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): must provide a file handle or pipe
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Sending performRunAction: to <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7fe12d932b50> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7fe12d932b50>
  1: Sending performAction: to <DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell: 0x7fe12d933180> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7fe12d932b50>
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff90c858b6 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x000000010fd86d73 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff85ef3f51 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff90c856bc +[NSException raise:format:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff90412dce NOCOPY_SETTER_IMPL (in Foundation)
  5  0x0000000112528c6b __48-[DVTDeveloperModeHelper isDeveloperModeEnabled]_block_invoke (in DVTDeveloperModeHelper)
  6  0x0000000112528ba6 -[DVTDeveloperModeHelper isDeveloperModeEnabled] (in DVTDeveloperModeHelper)
  7  0x0000000112529160 __63-[DVTDeveloperModeAlertHelper _shouldAskUserAboutDeveloperMode]_block_invoke (in DVTDeveloperModeHelper)
  8  0x00007fff8eaebc74 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9  0x00007fff8eaebbe2 dispatch_once_f (in libdispatch.dylib)
 10  0x0000000112529108 -[DVTDeveloperModeAlertHelper _shouldAskUserAboutDeveloperMode] (in DVTDeveloperModeHelper)
 11  0x00000001125291c0 -[DVTDeveloperModeAlertHelper _askToEnableDeveloperModeIfNecessary] (in DVTDeveloperModeHelper)
 12  0x0000000110fbf657 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _performDebuggableSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 13  0x0000000110fc02a8 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _runScheme:runDestination:invocationRecord:] (in IDEKit)
 14  0x0000000110f0673b -[IDEWorkspaceTabController runActiveRunContext:] (in IDEKit)
 15  0x00000001110191b1 -[IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton performRunAction:] (in IDEKit)
 16  0x00007fff8b0410da -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 17  0x0000000110467aff __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 18  0x000000010fd86ab1 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 19  0x00000001102995ba -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 20  0x000000011045c220 -[DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell performAction:] (in DVTKit)
 21  0x00007fff8b0410da -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 22  0x0000000110467aff __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 23  0x000000010fd86ab1 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 24  0x00000001102995ba -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 25  0x0000000110364a74 -[DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in DVTKit)
 26  0x00007fff8b03e4d6 -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 27  0x0000000110380832 -[DVTMainStatusAwareButton mouseDown:] (in DVTKit)
 28  0x00000001103807c3 -[DVTRolloverTrackingButton mouseDown:] (in DVTKit)
 29  0x00007fff8b037918 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 30  0x00007fff8b031f48 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 31  0x0000000110e0083b -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 32  0x00007fff8af53599 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 33  0x00007fff8aefd563 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 34  0x00007fff882ea60d start (in libdyld.dylib)

Performing @selector(performRunAction:) from sender IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton 0x7fe12d932b50
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbf8a6 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e53c5 pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c54fb7e abort + 125
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000110ffd7af +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:reason:] + 775
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000110ffe9fd -[IDEAssertionHandler handleUncaughtException:] + 919
5   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000110ffeaa8 IDEHandleUncaughtException + 77
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90d2ba82 __handleUncaughtException + 706
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff85ef43e0 _objc_terminate() + 94
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff89eccebf std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 6
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff89eccf36 std::terminate() + 54
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff85ef418c objc_terminate + 9
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8eaebc88 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8eaebbe2 dispatch_once_f + 79
13  com.apple.dt.DVTDeveloperModeHelper 0x0000000112529108 -[DVTDeveloperModeAlertHelper _shouldAskUserAboutDeveloperMode] + 103
14  com.apple.dt.DVTDeveloperModeHelper 0x00000001125291c0 -[DVTDeveloperModeAlertHelper _askToEnableDeveloperModeIfNecessary] + 29
15  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000110fbf657 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _performDebuggableSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:] + 1074
16  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000110fc02a8 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _runScheme:runDestination:invocationRecord:] + 275
17  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000110f0673b -[IDEWorkspaceTabController runActiveRunContext:] + 188
18  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001110191b1 -[IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton performRunAction:] + 500
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b0410da -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 327
20  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000110467aff __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke + 351
21  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010fd86ab1 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint + 82
22  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x00000001102995ba -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 344
23  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000011045c220 -[DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell performAction:] + 198
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b0410da -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 327
25  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000110467aff __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke + 351
26  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010fd86ab1 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint + 82
27  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x00000001102995ba -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 344
28  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000110364a74 -[DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 693
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b03e4d6 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 706
30  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000110380832 -[DVTMainStatusAwareButton mouseDown:] + 97
31  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x00000001103807c3 -[DVTRolloverTrackingButton mouseDown:] + 57
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b037918 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 11303
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b031f48 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2021
34  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000110e0083b -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] + 444
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8af53599 -[NSApplication run] + 646
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8aefd563 NSApplicationMain + 940
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff882ea60d start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbfeaa __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e5f4e _pthread_wqthread + 324
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e8fd9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cc06a2 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8eaedda6 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 227
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8eaedcb2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbba76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbad74 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c20ee5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c27179 __CFRunLoopRun + 1497
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c267b3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff902b2a47 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9030cc73 __NSThread__main__ + 1319
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e490f _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e47a0 _pthread_start + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e8fe9 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbf9ea __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c66a53 __CFSocketManager + 867
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e490f _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e47a0 _pthread_start + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e8fe9 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbba76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbad74 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c20ee5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c27179 __CFRunLoopRun + 1497
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c267b3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000011a65e81a -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 164
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9030cc73 __NSThread__main__ + 1319
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e490f _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e47a0 _pthread_start + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e8fe9 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbba76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbad74 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c20ee5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c27179 __CFRunLoopRun + 1497
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c267b3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff903122fc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff902af10a -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x000000011b2eb96b -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 132
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9030cc73 __NSThread__main__ + 1319
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e490f _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e47a0 _pthread_start + 131
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e8fe9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbf756 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e6c7b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff90deca8c CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 656
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff90dec7e3 startIOThread(void*) + 147
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e490f _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e47a0 _pthread_start + 131
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e8fe9 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbba76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbad74 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c20ee5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c27179 __CFRunLoopRun + 1497
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c267b3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b2c97f8 _NSEventThread + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e490f _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e47a0 _pthread_start + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e8fe9 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbfeaa __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e5f4e _pthread_wqthread + 324
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e8fd9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff86cbfa7a __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c56ee24 nanosleep + 200
2   com.apple.CoreSymbolication     0x00007fff92006841 0x7fff91ff3000 + 79937
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e490f _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e47a0 _pthread_start + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f5e8fe9 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff77d89310  rcx: 0x00007fff4ff20a28  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000707  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff4ff20a50  rsp: 0x00007fff4ff20a28
   r8: 0x00007fe12a80b200   r9: 0x0000000000000081  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff4ff20b68  r13: 0x00000001116cf4e8  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x00007fe12dd27670
  rip: 0x00007fff86cbf8a6  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x000000011507e000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x10fcde000 -        0x10fcdeff7  com.apple.dt.Xcode (5.0.2 - 3335.32) <325477C5-32DB-3091-91B7-41B670C5C0ED> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskManagement.framework/Versions/A/DiskManagement

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 14
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 227454
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=350.7M resident=79.7M(23%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=271.0M(77%)
Writable regions: Total=1.2G written=40.0M(3%) resident=74.4M(6%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.1G(94%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
CG backing stores                    3812K
CG image                              824K
CG raster data                        292K
CG shared images                      212K
CoreAnimation                         480K
CoreData                                4K
CoreData Object IDs                  4100K
CoreImage                              72K
CoreServices                          592K
Dispatch continuations               16.0M
IOKit                                 404K
Image IO                              360K
JS JIT generated code                   8K
JS JIT generated code (reserved)      1.0G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                       8K
MALLOC                              126.3M
MALLOC (admin)                         32K
Memory Tag 242                         12K
Memory Tag 249                        156K
Memory Tag 251                         16K
OpenCL                                 68K
SQLite page cache                    1632K
STACK GUARD                          56.0M
Stack                                12.2M
VM_ALLOCATE                          16.5M
WebKit Malloc                        1272K
__DATA                               46.2M
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                           87.8M
__TEXT                              263.1M
__UNICODE                             544K
mapped file                         165.9M
shared memory                           4K
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                 1.8G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space      805.3M
```

What is the solution for this problem?

Regards

Comment: I am talking about XCode app launch button.

Comment: what type of template you used?

Comment: I created an empty project

Comment: there must be something wrong with that particular project when it was created by Xcode. have you tried creating another empty application and it did not work as well? if so you may have to quit Xcode and restart your machine and try doing it again. if the problem persist and it does that every time you try using this template, there may be an issue with this temple in your Xcode, so you may have to reload the Xcode back to your machine again to remove that issue. but try the first two steps first.

Answer (score 4):

Try with a new one. If it still crashing then edit the scheme and change the debugger from `LLDB` to `GDB` (or vice versa). Before build your app don't forget to "Clean Your Project" `(shift + command + k)` and "iOS Simulator" `(Reset Content and setting)` Hope it solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem using Xcode 5.1.1, both with a project that worked find on the previous version of Xcode and on example code downloaded from Apple.  It seems to be a problem with the debugger.  As of Xcode 5.x the gdb debugger is no longer available, only LLDB, and there seems to be a problem with LLDB.

I was able to prevent the crash by turning off the use of LLDB.   To do so, select Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme, and then select "None" for the debugger.    After that, Xcode doesn't crash and the app starts on the simulator as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not the empty project, but instead the record the Xcode keeps related to enable-for-developer mode.  This is in the call path of where it crashes. I recommend removing Xcode from your system and re-installing it.